# How to find child nodes and store in different objects

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<class name="EmployeeData.Employee">
  <property emp="1">
    <empid>12345678</empid>
    <empname>ABC1</empname>
    <project>XYZ1</project>
  </property>
  <property emp="2">
    <empid>87654321</empid>
    <empname>ABC2</empname>
    <project>XYZ2</project>
  </property>
</class>
```

In the above XML doc I have two nodes by name `property`. I need to parse through it and store the values: `"12345678","ABC1","XYZ1"` in one object and `"87654321","ABC2","XYZ2"` in another. Also I should be able to use the two objects later whenever and wherever I need. How can I do this?

Comment: but what have you tried?

Comment: When I tried parsing the file, I could just end up finding data related to <property emp='2'> only.

Comment: show us your attempt..

Comment: You can deserialize this xml into C# object.
See example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ2XML

```
var doc=XDocument.Load(url);
var output= doc.Elements("property").Select(x=>
              new
              {
                    empid=x.Element("empid").Value,
                    empname=x.Element("empname").Value,
                    project=x.Element("project").Value
              }
);
```

Now you can iterate over output

```
foreach(var property in output)
{
    property.empid;
    property.empname;
    property.project;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get each <property>

```
XmlDocument xdoctest = new XmlDocument();    
xdoctest.LoadXml("...");   
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoctest.SelectNodes("class/property");
```

Then loop through each property node, loop through each element of that node and get value. In this example I append to a StringBuilder but edit it to suit your needs.

```
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    StringBuilder nodeString = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(XmlElement elm in node)
    {
        nodeString.Append(elm.InnerText + ",");
    }
    // Remove last ,
    nodeString = new StringBuilder(nodeString.ToString().Substring(0, nodeString.Length - 1));
    Console.WriteLine(nodeString);
}
```

Based on the XML you gave the output is:

```
12345678,ABC1,XYZ1
87654321,ABC2,XYZ2
```